# Maintain Original Column Names with XLConnect readWorksheet in R

Tags: r, excel, xlconnect

I am reading in the column header from a `.xlsx` file using `XLConnect::readWorksheet`.  The issue is that the column header contains `/` and `spaces` between words, which are replaced with `.` by the package when loading.

For example, an Excel spreadsheet with header `First Name` and `Sex/Gender` will appear in R as `First.Name` and `Sex.Gender`.

This is a problem, because I don't know if `.` represents a `/` or a `space`.

Is there a way to override this feature and simulate `data.table` functionality where column names are maintained and wrapped in a ` (backtick)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an argument of check.names, with a default value of TRUE, if you change it to FALSE, then the column names will be maintained.

```
XLConnect::readWorksheet(loadWorkbook("C:/Book1.xlsx"), sheet = 1, check.names = FALSE)
```

You may also want to use the readxl packages as in the example:

```
readxl::read_excel("C:/Book1.xlsx")
```

This doesn't have an option for check.names or similar, but the default behavior does not change the column names.